# Autocompletado con llamada Ajax en AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http

Quiero implementar un autoCompletado utilizando una llamada Ajax por ejemplo:

```
this.getCliente = function(data){
    return $http.post(UrlobtenerDatosUsuario,data);
 }
```

el cual retorna un Json segun los parametros que envie.
Ahora una vez obtenida la data realizar la busqueda utilizando autocompletado a partir de 3 digito.

alguien por favor puede ayudarme dandome algun guia?

Comment: Esto te podría ayudar http://www.grabthiscode.com/programacion/autocompletado-de-formularios-con-jquery-y-ajax/

Comment: Estás usando bootstrap?

Comment: No, es puro AngularJs algo de Jquery para el HTML y CSS, lo que pasa es que ya tengo los html Maquetados y tengo que ver la implementación del autocompleted y no malograr el diseño ya predefinido.

Comment: el maquetado vino con este jquery: <script src="assets/js/third-party/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script> que lo utiliza para autocompleted pero al hacer la parte del angular no lo puedo reutilizar.

Comment: La pregunta es porque [`ui-bootstrap`](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) que está diseñado para angular y bootstrap viene con la directiva [`typeahead`](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) que te puede servir para lo que quieres.

Comment: Bueno, podria ser una solución, tendria que agregar bootstrap a mi proyecto para utilizar ese autocompleted, no tendria problemas con eso. Y como podria implementarlo? Podrias ayudarme por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Para hacer esto puedes asignar un modelo para el input de búsqueda y escuchar los cambios con `ng-change` usando un retardo con `$timeout` para darle tiempo al usuario que termine de ingresar su búsqueda, luego tomas ese valor para hacer la petición al servidor y por ultimo muestras N número de resultados en una lista. Aqui te dejo un ejemplo:

Template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="textoBusqueda" ng-change="buscar(textoBusqueda)"> 

<span ng-show="cargando">Cargando...</span>

<div class="resultadosBusqueda">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="sugerencia in results" ng-click="clienteSeleccionado = sugerencia">
        {{ sugerancia.nombre }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <h2 ng-if="clienteSelecionado">
    <Strong>Cliente Seleccionado: </Strong> {{ clienteSeleccionado.nombre }}
  </h2>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app.clientes')
.controller('clientesCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http', 
    function($scope, clientesService, $timeout, $http){
      $scope.results = [];
      $scope.cargando = false;
      $scope.clienteSeleccionado = null;

      var URL_CLIENTES = 'api/v1/clientes/';

      // Autocompletado Busqueda 
      var timer = null;
      $scope.buscar = function(val){
        if(timer) $timeout.cancel(timer);
        timer = $timeout(exc, 800); //800 milisegundos de retardo
        function exc(){
          console.log('buscando...');
          $scope.getClientes(val);
        }
      }

      // Llamada al servidor
      $scope.getClientes = function(val){
        $scope.cargando = true; //mostrar "cargando en la vista"
        return $http.post(URL_CLIENTES+'?limit=10', { q: val}).then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $scope.results = response.data; 
            $scope.cargando = false;
        }); 
      };
}]);
```

Usando css puedes darle estilos a los `ul>li` para que salga en forma pegados al inputs como opciones a completar.